# BlueImp Jquery file upload fail callback called multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using BlueImp's jQuery fileupload

```
var fileInput = $('#'+file_up_id+'_select');        
            var fileUploadObj = $(fileInput).fileupload({
                url: file_up_submitUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                maxNumberOfFiles:1,
                autoUpload: false,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
            })
            .on('fileuploadadd',onFileSelect)
            .on('fileuploadprogressall',onFileUploadProgress)
            .on('fileuploaddone',onFileUploadDone)
            .on('fileuploadfail',onFileUploadFail);

            onFileUploadProgress=function (e, data) {               
                uploadProgress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
          }
          onFileUploadFail=function (e, data) {
                console.log("failed");
          }
          onFileUploadDone=function (e, data) {
                console.log("done");
            }
```

HTML is

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    <b>Select a file</b><input type='file' id='myImgUpload_select' name='files[]' single />
</form>
```

My problem is when the upload fails, the fileuploadfailed callback is invoked multiple times. Otherwise everything works fine

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it fail multiple times for one file or one time per file?

Comment: It fails only once for one file..

Comment: It sounds like this is by design. I've contributed to the file upload project and the intention is to send a fail for each individual file that failed and a success for each individual file that succeeded. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: my problem is even if the file upload fails only once, the callback is invoked multiple times

Comment: So you've uploaded 3 files. 1 file fails and 2 succeed. You are getting 3 fail messages? Or all three failed and you get the fail message for all three?

Comment: I am uploading only one file.. it fails and I get 4 callbacks

Comment: What is causing your file to fail the upload? Is there a place I can see / reproduce this? I'm trying to recreate locally. Also, are you using the latest version?

Comment: Finally I found what the issue was.. My page was built using 4 partial JSP files. and each jsp was loading the script file. I am thinking the on("fileuploadfail") gets registered four times. It is strange that the "fileuploaddone" does not get registered 4 times. Thanks a lot for your help!